# действия с указателями

Tags: c++, указатели, операторы

```
public:
Integer(int n=0): num(n){}
void get_Sum(const Number &n)
{
    num += ((Integer*)&n)->num;
}
```

Пожалуйста, объясните, как работает функция `get_Sum`. Что обозначает `(Integer*)&n` и `->num`

Comment: Пожалуйста, указывайте язык программирования в метках

Comment: `((Integer*)&n)->num` можно заменить на `n.num` в данном случае.

Comment: @dzhioev класс `Number` может ничего не знать о поле `num`

Comment: @PavelParshin, сорри, не заметил, что аргумент имеет тип Number, а не Integer.

Answer (score 4):

Функция `get_Sum(const Number&)` принимает в качестве аргумента переменную типа `Number` по ссылке (из-за использования `&`).

Внутри функции:

1. `&n` = получаем указатель на область памяти, в которой хранится значение переменной `n`.
2. `(Integer*) &n` - полученный указатель типа `Number*` приводим к указателю типа `Integer*`.
3. `((Integer*) &n)->num` - получив указатель типа `Integer*`, обращаемся к полю `num` класса `Integer` переменной `n`.

Comment: странно, что не заиспользовали static_cast<const Integer&>(n).num; (http://ideone.com/MiSXFP) или dynamic_cast, что бы получить какую-то гарантию, что кастоваться оно может. Судя по всему, Number тут базовый класс. Да ещё и константность снимается. Что-то подсказывает, что там сильно внимательно на классы смотреть нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Функция вообще крайне запутанна.
Так гораздо понятнее:

```
class Integer
{
public:
  Integer(int n = 0) : num_(n) {}
  int num() const { return num_; }
  void setNum(int n) { num_ = n; }
private:
  int num_;
};

class Number
{
public:
  Number() : value_(0) {}
  int value() const { return value_; }
  void setValue(int n) { value_ = n; }
private:
  int value_;
};

int get_Sum(int a, int b)
{
  return a + b;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  Integer a;
  a.setNum(2);
  Number b;
  b.setValue(5);

  Integer c(a.num() + b.value());

  std::cout << "a.num() = " << a.num() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "b.value() = " << b.value() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "c.num() = " << c.num() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}

// Вывод:
// a.num() = 2
// b.value() = 5
// c.num() = 7
```

Рекомендация: при проектировании в качестве аргументов функции (любой функции!) передавайте необходимый, но достаточный минимум сведений о контексте выполнения. Применительно к вашему коду: функции `get_Sum` не нужен аргумент типа `Number`, если ей достаточно `int`.

И да, как уже сказали, кастить таким образом: `((Integer*)&n)` - не есть хорошо. Старайтесь писать код, избегая вызовов функций приведения типов. А в необходимых случаях используйте `static_cast`, `dynamic_cast` и `const_cast`.